# force download excel file not working on web server

Tags: php, excel

This following coding working on localhost perfectly for force to download excel file, but doesn't working on web server.

```
$par_name="worker_report";
$nwdatetime=date('d-m-Y h-i-s');
$fi = $par_name."_". $nwdatetime;
$extns=".xls";
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');  
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fi.$extns);  

header("Pragma: ");  
header("Cache-Control: ");  
$_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
```

Comment: enable error log and display the error here.

Comment: This may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542455/force-download-script

Comment: Did that really work on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the content type to `Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel`

Or try this code if works.

```
$par_name="worker_report";
$nwdatetime=date('d-m-Y h-i-s');
$fi = $par_name."_". $nwdatetime;
$extns=".xls";

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fi.$extns);
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`application/vnd.ms-excel` is for `.xls` files created with the Excel5 Writer.

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` is used for .xlsx files created with the Excel2007 Writer

So you have to check what are you doing there

> `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');`  is for `.xls` files
>
> `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');`  is for `.xlsx` files